# Why was a question suitable for Stack Overflow closed, instead of being migrated

Tags: discussion, migration, close-reasons, closed-questions

Yesterday, [Jessica Burnett](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/15383/jessica-burnett) asked this question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14209/css-set-string-content-properties.

Since the question is about code that does not work (as opposed to code that could be improved), [ANeves](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/7773/aneves) politely suggested to the OP to [post such questions on Stack Overflow](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/14209/css-set-string-content-properties#comment-22997). So far so good.

However, today ANeves & [Michael K](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/110/michael-k) closed the question as being off-topic.

Is this our policy here, to close questions that are suitable for other StackExchange sites? Somehow I had gotten the feeling that such questions should rather be migrated to their proper home!?

Comment: In general, marginal questions are never migrated (i.e. "Don't Migrate Crap"). Just because a question *can* be migrated doesn't mean that it *should.* The OP can always repost on the correct site, if they're so inclined. A migration is essentially equivalent to closing as "off-topic." (it doesn't belong here, it belongs over there).

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Are you referring to off-topic questions in general, or to this specific question? I cannot see any way for the question to be considered crap.

Comment: The original question is not a great one. The cross-posted one is an improvement over the original.  In the Teacher's Lounge (the super sekrit chatroom for moderators) we are often asked if a question would be a good fit for migration.  95% of the time, we say no.  In this particular case, I think we would have OK'd it.

Comment: The reason this is true is the same reason that the question is being posted on the wrong site in the first place. It is the same reason that a post seldom has a one-character grammatical error in it (and why SE limits trivial edits); there are almost always *multiple* errors in such posts, not just one.

Comment: It would probably be best to delete our copy then, because it doesn't add any value. It will just be clutter if someone is Googling for the problem; we have no answers and no useful comments. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that's probably fine.

Comment: @MichaelK - I wholehardedly agree. Since it hasn't been migrated, its only usefulness is in increasing the noise level around here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, it was [cross-posted to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764700/using-css-string-set-property-and-content-method), and it has an accepted answer there. You're correct that it belonged there, but there was no need to migrate it since the OP had already posted there.

I'll add a comment to the post to make it clear.

EDIT: Based on the discussion above, I've deleted our copy of the question. We have no answers or useful comments, and the question on SO is improved and has a good answer. Our copy is just noise at this point.

Comment: I hadn't realized that Jessica had cross-posted it on SO herself. Is there no way to link the 2 on a deeper level (not just by merely adding a comment)?

Comment: I'll talk to the SO mods and see if they would be willing to merge the question if we migrated it to them - that would look like a plain migration to us. Since it's got an accepted answer I'm not sure it's really worth it though. We'll see what they think.

Comment: Sounds OK. Was actually more concerned about our policy than about this specific question. Thanks.