# Migrating questions to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, migration

In [this](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/581/why-was-a-question-suitable-for-stack-overflow-closed-instead-of-being-migrated) question, the poster noticed that the question was closed rather than being migrated.  Comments say that the question was cross-posted, so it was just closed on our site.

In the comments, it appears that some people think that we should tell the poster to re-post to the site where the question would be on-topic.

On Stack Overflow, most people are strongly against telling people to cross-post.  Is this sentiment the same across all SE sites?

I know we are Beta, so I assume it is harder for us to migrate questions to other sites.  Have we fallen into the mindset that the user should delete their post here and re-post on the site where their question will be on-topic?

Why are we closing these questions as opposed to migrating them?

Migrating these questions would give a link back to Code Review which, in my opinion, would be a good advertisement for our site inside the SE network.

Comment: The software does not offer us an option to migrate a question to Stack Overflow. So it is not surprising that we don't do this.

Comment: I figured that it was a manual thing.  the software must only be able to migrate away from stackoverflow?

Comment: It's policy. [See here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/719/11728): "Until we are out of beta, only the moderators can migrate posts."

Comment: that is what I was thinking.  I was flagging posts for Migration, so I was wondering why we weren't migrating them?  the flags were found helpful,  maybe they were helpful in terms of they were off-topic here but not completely on-topic for StackOverflow?

Comment: It's not a cross-post if the original question is closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gareth Rees is correct about it being impossible to migrate directly due to our beta state.  Until we graduate, we'll have to continue closing and/or flagging for migration.

I don't see this entirely as a bad thing, though.  This will give us the opportunity to get used to knowing exactly which questions belong on SO.  Sure, it's already simple enough (not working, understanding code snippets, etc.), but some questions can still be tossed out by them.  Essentially, the question has to

1. be on-topic for SO and
2. not be crap.

Just because they *may* sometimes dump their trash here (usually due to not knowing exactly what we allow), doesn't mean we have to do the same. ;-)

Although this may not be an issue for us per se, there's the possibility of migrating an off-topic question that was already originally asked over there.  In other words, someone tells the OP to post the question here instead of flagging it for migration.  So, we see that it's off-topic, then send it over there... and they have an exact duplicate.  Not a big deal I suppose, but what I'm saying is that *both* sites need to be familiar with the target site's FAQ.  There's too many people to count on that, though I'm not sure if a moderator needs to be flagged for each migration request.

Comment: That's right, our network-wide policy is **[don't migrate crap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446/175128)**. If we're reasonably sure that the question will be closed on the target site anyway, there is no use in migrating it.

Comment: @codesparkle: Thanks. :-) Of all my digging around on MSO, I haven't yet come across that answer.